# Creating a WAR file using Java

Tags: java, tomcat, war

How do I create a deployable WAR file for Apache Tomcat servers **programmatically with Java**?

Is there a library for such a task?

I am working on a small own IDE for special purposes. The IDE is written in Java and JavaScript, so I need to create the WAR file using those.

Comment: Don't use Ant but maven instead. It is much more powerful and also easier to use in my opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to build it from code try to do it from the command line with

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = rt.exec("jar cvf /path/to/your/project/your-file.war");
```

Of course, the same thing would work using ANT or Maven (as long as those tools are installed on the final platform).

Edit: added improvement suggestion

Comment: I want to create it programmatically, not by using ANT scripts (except if I were able to access those programmatically).

Comment: But I don't think I am, am I?

Comment: you do not need ant for the command line commands. you can call them through java and it will create the file for you. as you said you are implementing an own ide, i don't know if you want to implement ant support.

Comment: How am I able to call them through Java? Only by using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` command, or is there a better way?

Comment: I think this is the best practice  
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = rt.exec("your command");

Comment: Okay, thanks! I'll improve your answer. Think it's the easier way than creating it by my own.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of libraries, but a WAR file is just a ZIP file with a different ending.

Just create the inner folder structure and files (google the java code for that) and package as zip (java has methods for that too I think, again google) and rename the file from "myfile.zip" to "myfile.war"

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you would do it using the IDE you have. But a WAR file has the following structure:

- web resources go to the root
- project classes (including their package folders) go to a folder WEB-INF/classes
- project dependency jars go to WEB-INF/lib

So if you want to build a WAR by hand, you need to create that file structure inside a zip file with a .war extension and you need to copy that to the proper location of the server to deploy it. Most servers also allow 'exploded deployment', meaning that you don't need an actual war file, you can just deploy the stuff to a directory with the same name as your war (IE. 'myapp.war').

Answer (score 0):

You can do this a number of ways, for a quick example if you are using maven you just need to use `<packaging>war</packaging>`

You could just export the war as has been mentioned, but it's not exactly "programmatic".

If you're using Ant - you can find a tutorial for this [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ant/ant_creating_war_files.htm)

Answer (score -2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
```

```
<path id="compile.classpath">
    <fileset dir="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib">
        <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</path>

<target name="init">
    <mkdir dir="build/classes"/>
    <mkdir dir="dist" />
</target>

<target name="compile" depends="init" >
    <javac destdir="build/classes" debug="true" srcdir="src">
        <classpath refid="compile.classpath"/>
    </javac>
</target>

<target name="war" depends="compile">
    <war destfile="/APP/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/all/deploy/DispatchActionEx.war" webxml="WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml">         
        <fileset dir="WebContent"/>
        <lib dir="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib"/>         
        <classes dir="build/classes"/>
    </war>
</target>

<target name="clean">       
</target>
```

1. Just write an build.xml file(i have give an example),
2. change "project name" and "war destfile" which will be ".../apache-tomcat/webapps/projectname.war"
3. put it in your project folder
4. open it in eclipse.
5. right click on it>>run as>>ant build
6. check whether the war file is created in the webapps folder in apache-tomcat

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. I want to create a WAR file `programmatically in Java` for my `own IDE`. As a result, using a 3rd Party IDE isn't a solution at all.